# Correlation coefficient and p value for each row within a datafarme

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, stat

I have a matrix, looks like following,

```
foo = pd.DataFrame(
        [['ASP1',12.45,12.65,1.54,1.56],
        ['ASP2',4.5,1.4,0.03,1.987],
        ['ASP3',0.12,0.34,0.45,0.9],
        ['ASP4',0.65,0.789,0.01,0.876]],
        columns = ('Sam','C1','C2','B1','B2'))
foo
    Sam C1  C2  B1  B2
0   ASP1    12.45   12.650  1.54    1.560
1   ASP2    4.50    1.400   0.03    1.987
2   ASP3    0.12    0.340   0.45    0.900
3   ASP4    0.65    0.789   0.01    0.876
```

And I wanted to do correlation test for each row in Sam between the columns C1..C2 and B1..B2. And at the end, I am aiming a resulting matrix as follows,

```
foo_result = pd.DataFrame(
        [['C',0.76,0.06],
        ['B',0.34,0.10]],
        columns = ('Gen','Correlation_coefficent','P-value'))
foo_result

    Gene    Correlation_coefficent  P-value
0   C   0.76    0.060
1   B   0.34    0.100
```

Any suggestions or solutions would be great.
Thank you

Comment: which correlation? [scipy-docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html) list a whole bunch of them

Comment: pearsonr(x, y) is what i need to do

Comment: Do you want `C` and `B` per Sam or generally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
from scipy.stats import pearsonr

c_values = [column for column in foo.columns.tolist() if column.startswith('C')]
b_values = [column for column in foo.columns.tolist() if column.startswith('B')]

foo['Correlation_coefficent'], foo['P-value'] = zip(*foo.T.apply(lambda x: pearsonr(x[c_values], x[b_values])))
foo_result = foo[['Sam', 'Correlation_coefficent','P-value']]
```

Output:

```
    Sam  Correlation_coefficent  P-value
0  ASP1                     1.0      0.0
1  ASP2                    -1.0      0.0
2  ASP3                     1.0      0.0
3  ASP4                     1.0      0.0
```

Reason why you have these results is the number of variables. Hope your original has at least 3 values.

Comment: Thanks But I have 120 columns with C as the suffix and so as with B. So in that case, I am wondering how can I show the columns there. ? would be great if you could guide me little more

Comment: I tried to put it into iterating rows. like this, 
for r in foo.iterrows():
    r['Correlation_coefficent'], r['P-value'] = zip(*r.T.apply(lambda x: pearsonr([x.C1, x.C2], [x.B1, x.B2])))
    foo_result = r[['Sam', 'Correlation_coefficent','P-value']] But it is throwing error as, AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'T'

Comment: Thank you also actually as I said data frame is really big so the columns are not in order as it in the example. I mean the column names are not like C1, c2, B1, B2. But then its like C1,C2,...Cn, B4,B6...Bn. And so its throwing error now as, ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Comment: Well your `n` must be the same. Same number of `C` and `B` columns.

Comment: Well, df.shape is 224, its 112 on C and 112 on B columns.

Comment: Without `Sam` column or with?

Comment: Actually, I am sorry I showed my aimed output as different from intended in my primary question. Sorry for your time :(

Comment: Without Sam Sam column is index . In my real df

Comment: Well, you can accept this answer and propose a new question :)

Comment: Well, I accepted your answer but it's a minor change I just edited now.Instead of correlations for Sam, I need correlations for columns I mean Between B and C like now. Do you think Still I need to propose a new question?

Comment: Well it is a new question, I can try and help you with this, but you may find new answers if you write question like this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143694/discussion-between-user1017373-and-zipa).

Answer (score 1):

I would use [DataFrame.apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

```
from scipy.stats import pearsonr
foo[['corr_coef', 'p_value']] = foo.apply(lambda x: pearsonr(x=x[1:3], y=x[3:5]), axis=1).apply(pd.Series)
```

The output is

```
    Sam     C1      C2    B1     B2  corr_coef  p_value
0  ASP1  12.45  12.650  1.54  1.560        1.0      0.0
1  ASP2   4.50   1.400  0.03  1.987       -1.0      0.0
2  ASP3   0.12   0.340  0.45  0.900        1.0      0.0
3  ASP4   0.65   0.789  0.01  0.876        1.0      0.0
```

If you have 112 columns of each C and B, you should use `pearsonr(x=x[1:113], y=x[113:125])`

Comment: Thanks, this works, but I changed my primary question a little bit.